# Using Automator to set Music track as loved

Tags: applescript, automator, music

I am new to Automator and AppleScript and I'm trying to do something I thought was fairly simply, using an AppleScript to set a track in Music to loved.

Here is the AppleScript I'm trying:

```
tell application "Music"
    set loved of current track to true
end tell
```

I am getting the following error when I try to run it:
`Music got an error: Unknown object type.`

I've seen a few guides where people used this command in Itunes and also in Music. Why doesn't this work for me?

Comment: `tell application "Music" to set loved of current track to true` only works if the _track_ that is currently playing is in your **Library** as a physical _file_ on disk, or disc if **CD**, and does not work on _tracks_ that are being _streamed_.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Unfortunate though. Thanks!